# exponential functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I am confused of solving exponential functions they look easy but can't solve it.
1: $$\large e^{8\cdot\ln(b^{1/4})}$$

and this one solving for x:
1: $$\ln(6x-2) = 5$$

FYI : It's not an assignment. i am trying to solve it for my understanding

Comment: rememer this: $$A = e^a \iff a = \ln(A)$$

Comment: Hints
$$e^{ab}=(e^a)^b=(e^b)^a\\ \ln a^b = b\ln a$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you probably just need to simplify it. Because it isn't an equation, you can't really "solve'' it for anything.

Here's how you could simplify that expression:

\begin{align*}
e^{8\ln\left(b^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)} &= e^{\ln\left(b^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^8} \\
&= e^{\ln\left(b^{\frac{8}{4}}\right)} \\
&= e^{\ln\left(b^{2}\right)} \\
&= b^2
\end{align*}
The first step involves using exponent rules for natural logs (namely, that $a\log b = \log b^a$), and the last part uses the fact that $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are $\textit{inverses}$; i.e., that $e^{\ln x} = x$ and $\ln \left(e^x\right) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't equal to anything to solve so it's unknown, the other is
$$\ln(6x-2)=5$$
$$6x-2=e^5$$
$$6x=e^5+2$$
$$x=\frac{e^5+2}{6}$$

Comment: how can i simplify that? is looks scary to me... Thanks

Comment: It's as simple as you get, you can approximate it with $e^5$ is almost 148